# focus on parent tab on close of the child tab using jquery-chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I open a child tab by clicking a link on my parent tab.After some operation, I close the child tab and the focus should go to the parent tab, even if I opened some other tab before closing the child tab.I am able to refresh the parent tab but couldn't get focus on it.If I opened another tab in between after closing the child the focus goes to previously taken tab, that is a normal behaviour in chrome.Can I have an option to change that using javascript/JQuery?